# How to write a parsed XML file into another file in Java

Tags: java, xml, file-io, sax

I am parsing an XML file which is `1.2 GB` using `SAX Parser` in Java. The result was not complete in the `Console`. What I am trying to do is writing the parsed XML file into another file. Here is my code for parsing the XML file using SAX:

```
public class Parser extends DefaultHandler
{

public void startDocument()
{
System.out.println("Begin parsing the document .. ");
}

public void endDocument()
{
System.out.println("End parsing document ..");
}

public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,String rawName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException 
{
System.out.print("<" + rawName + ">");
}

public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String rawName) throws SAXException 
 {
System.out.print("</" + rawName + ">");
 }

public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException 
 {
for (int i=0; i<(start + length); i++)
{
    System.out.print(ch[i]);
}
}
}
```

Here is the `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args ) throws IOException, SAXException
{
XMLReader p = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
p.setContentHandler(new Parser());
p.parse("dblp.xml");
}
```

I would like to write all the contents of this XML file into a text file at least. I am also thinking to write the contents into another XML file. Could anyone please help me write the XML file contents. I have tried with the following code somehow:

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt"); 
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
```

Comment: Please explain what happened when you tried your code. It's not clear from your question what problem you are facing. Please also use consistent indentation when you include code samples, otherwise they are more difficult to read.

Comment: The code is parsing the XML file. All what I need is write the output of parsing into another text file for example.

Comment: You say in your question "*I have tried with the following code*". I'm asking what happened when you tried? I'm confused if you have some broken code you need us to help fix or whether you're hoping someone will write that code for you. If you include `@Duncan` in your response, I will be notified of your reply.

Comment: When I run the code, the output is displayed in the Console. I do not know how to write these output into a text file. It should not be broken. I just tested it with a little XML file. The output of parsing was displayed in the Console in Eclipse.

Comment: What you are looking for is to get the console output into a file since your parser is writing everything into the console

Comment: Yes. This is what I am looking for. Any idea how to do it in this way?

Comment: Ok, now I understand the requirement. You get a down-vote from me then, since you've not apparently tried to solve the problem. There are a myriad of documents on the Internet explaining how to write to files from Java. Please find one, try it, then come to us with any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your calls to `System.out.print` with calls to `fstream.write` - some of the calls are slightly different so read the Javadoc.

However, I am wondering why you are parsing the file if you are just trying to copy it? If your only objective is top copy it, just open an input stream, read a buffer of data and write it to your output stream, looping until you hit eof.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Basically, I could not open the file and cant understand why. I believe fstream.write can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect the console output to file by doing this:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("out.txt"));
System.setOut(out);
```

EDIT: The other answer to write directly to fstream is probably a better one.